# Java program. How do I loop my "isLucky" method through my array? Also, how do I print my results correctly in the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, compilation

First off, my program is not compiling. Any ideas? I have no idea why and my Eclipse program isn't working...

Also, how do I get my "isLucky" method to loop through my array?
And did I print out my results correctly in the main method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        luckyNumber1 = 7;
        luckyNumber2 = 13;
        luckyNumber3 = 18;


        int[] a=new int[10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers...");
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
            a[j] = sc.nextInt();

        boolean b = isLucky(a);

            int result; 

            if(b)
                result = sum(a);
            System.out.println(sum(a))
            else
                result = sumOfEvens(a);
            System.out.println(sumOfEvens(a))
    }

    public static int sum(int [ ] value)  
    {
          int i, total = 0;
          for(i=0; i<10; i++)
          {
              total = total + value[ i ];
          }

          return (total);
    }
    static int sumOfEvens(int array[]) 
    {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
    }
    public static boolean isLucky (int[] array) 
    {

        if ( array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 13 || array[i] == 18 )
            return true; 

        else
            return false;
    }

    // write the static methods isLucky, sum, and sumOfEvens

}
```

Comment: "Any ideas"? Read the compiler's error messages and fix your issues.

Comment: Your isLucky method definitely does not know what i is defined as. One first glance that's definitely one error. Fix that and then as mentioned above, take a look at the compilation error and fix it.

Comment: @rohit just compiled it on some browser compiler.  Now it just says FunArrays.java:25: error: 'else' without 'if'
   else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler error, `'else' without 'if'` is because you have something like this:

```
if(isOkay)
   doSomething();
   andThenDoSomethingElse();
else
   doAnotherThing();
   andEvenSomethingElse();
```

And you must put each block in curly braces, like this:

```
if(isOkay)  {
   doSomething();
   andThenDoSomethingElse();
}  else  {
   doAnotherThing();
   andEvenSomethingElse();
}
```

I strongly recommend using curly braces in all `if`s (and `whiles` and `for`s and everything else), even when there's only a single statement.

More information can be found at this question: *[Else without if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459510/else-without-if)*

Comment: Thank you for the tips and suggestions.  How would I put this into my main method though so it loops through the array?

Comment: I recommend you post new questions to ask these things. You've stuffed too many into this one.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there is no regulation that says we have to use code blocks. Syntax typically says that after we read the if we are looking for only one statement if your condition contains multiple statements then we do have to block that code up, another thing is try to keep that indentation whenever you enter methods conditions and then statements. Id love to write the easy route to get the output you desire. Think about this why are you sending these methods arrays? What is stopping you from simply looping in your main method and passing each iteration to these methods sum lucky, even...Your variables should usually be initialized at top or at the beginning of a method to have those around the life of a methods execution.Below is clearly not compile ready code, however this will edge you in the right place to understand this problem more than use brackets.

```
boolean isLucky;
int[] IntegerArray;
Scanner scan;
//Final for constant values Typically these would be in all uppercase to indicate to
//other that this is a final anywhere 
//in this class those will stick out.
final int luckyOne = 7;
final int luckyTwo = 13;
final int luckyThree = 18;

for(int i=0;i<IntegerArray.length;i++){
    //snag me Boolean value for this number
    isLucky();
    if(isLucky)//example of completely legal if statement adding a system.out statement 
               //means yes i have to block this
        sum(i);
    else
        even(i);


}
```